# PHP Failsafe If Unable to get_contents

Tags: php, json, api

```
$file = "https://www.some-api.com/?a=get_info";

$doge = (object) json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

if ($doge == false){
echo "failure";
}

else
{
[my code]
};
```

Every once and a while my script will fail, not all the time, simply intermittently. PHP error indicates that it's failing at the point of getting the file contents.

My attempt here with this else statement (that has not worked), was to display something different when the contents failed to be received. Is there a simple way for me to add a failsafe, so that either the script is reloaded or a different process is run if the api fails to respond properly?

Comment: `$data = file_get_contents(..); if (!$data) FALLBACK HERE`...? I'm unclear what the difficulty is here.

Answer (score 1):

This line will never be true...

```
if ($doge == false){
```

Given that `$doge` can never be false:

```
$doge = (object) json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
```

You *always* cast `$doge` to an object. You can't do that, and still check whether it's false. You need to perform the test *before* the cast, because...

- if `file_get_contents` fails, it returns `false`
- `json_decode(false)` returns `NULL`
- `(object) NULL` returns an object of type `stdClass`.

Therefore - it's impossible for `$doge` to be `false`, ever.

Try checking for failure *before* blindly `json_decoding` the result. Then, you don't even need the `(object)` cast.

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);

if (data) {
  $doge = json_decode($data);
  [my code]
} else {
  echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that, everything checked out, worked well for a while however now I still continue to get the error.
"file_get_contents(https://www.some-api.com/?a=get_info) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"

Answer (score 0):

In the [json_decode() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), it says that `FALSE` represents the false value. If it doesn't find any values to translate, it returns `NULL`. So be careful with that `if`...

The failsafe would by

```
$doge = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

if (!is_null($doge)){
  [decoded OK, your code here]
}
else
{
   [failsafe code here]
};
```

Comment: is there almost like a retry option? I think the difficulty is merely that split second that the API decides to either take to long, or not respond to this one request.
I guess in the end, I could loop that, couldn't I? and as long as the result was failed, it would try again?

Comment: You can enclose that in a loop, setting a flag if things went well, in order to exit the loop. The thing is, you might be performing that request a lot if the server is down for a while. You can add a counter with a number of retries, and then, if it keeps failing, abort. I think that a rewrite would be necessary (different functions, for instance) to keep the code that performs the get separated from the one that decides whether to do it again.